# Parse Line of Text and Add into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, parsing, avro

So I had an AVRO file and have not had any experience with that type of file, so I read the contents of that file and saved it to a text file, and so now I am trying to parse each line and add that to a MySQL table. I know how to connect to a MySQL database using Java and will basically execute a query that adds the data from each line. 
But the part I am having trouble with is parsing my data, basically this is what each line looks like (and each value is a 'String'):

```
{"content": "HTML", "GLOBALEVENTID": "331284989", "SQLDATE": "20140111", "MonthYear": "201401", "Year": "2014"}
```

So there are more columns than this but I shortened it, also the "content" field is actually the HTML of a webpage so it can contain a lot of random characters which I think could be an issue when parsing. But so my question is that I am trying to do parse out the values of each column and add it into an array (content, GLOBALEVENTID, etc.), so then I can add it to a MySQL table that already has these columns defined? Anything that can help me point me in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like JSON. I bet there is a library to parse that format with Java into a map object or something similar

Comment: This looks an awful lot like JSON...if you can verify that each line is JSON, then you have a ton of tools that you can use to parse this really painlessly...for example, check out http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

There are ***two*** approaches to solve this problem, depending on the what you are trying to achieve:

**Case 1) If this is just a one time load**
Answer: For a one time load, reading the AVRO file, parsing it to text file and then seeding data to MySQL using RDBMS APIs is too much work.
Instead, I would suggest to use the MySQL Import Utility.
If you go to the Schema Browser, and right click on the table name, you will find an option "Import..."
The options are explanatory. Usually, one time loads are done using a CSV or XLS file. You can modify your already existing program to convert AVRO file in to CSV file and use this file to Import data into MySQL table.

**Case 2) If AVRO file is to be read through a program, and this action will be done multiple times in future.**
In this case, you may use one of the many libraries (eg: Jackson/GSON), to parse the modified AVRO file into valid Java Object POJO. Make sure that the Object representation is a ORM (e.g: JPA/Hibernate) entity.
For example:

JSON: {"content": "HTML", "GLOBALEVENTID": "331284989", "SQLDATE": "20140111", "MonthYear": "201401", "Year": "2014"}

Class File:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTENT")
class Content {

@Id   
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SOME_SEQUENCE")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "DATA")
private String data;

@Column(name = "GLOBALEVENTID")
private String globalEventId;

@Column(name = "DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private String date;

....
....
}
```

Once the data has been parsed into the ORM entity, saving it to the Database should be very easy. As per your convinece, you may use entityManager.save/update or entitryManager.saveAll/updateAll